# Git: How to list cherry-picked commits?

Tags: git, logging, cherry-pick, git-cherry

How to list commits that were cherry-picked in Git?
Let's suppose the following scenario:
cp = cherry-pick commit

```
                         cp1         cp2          
master -----o------o------o-----o----o
            \            /          /
     branch1 \----o------o-----o---o---o
```

Is there a log command to list cherry-pick commits cp1 and cp2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could `git cherry` be what you're looking for?

Answer (score 9):

```
git cherry -v branch1 master
```

See [git-cherry](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) for documentation.

Comment: If you reverse the branches in the command above, `git cherry -v master branch1`, then you will see the new commit hash generated by cherry picking.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reflog
```

will show cherry-pick events.

Comment: This only works locally. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098095/git-can-i-view-the-reflog-of-a-remote) for more information.

Comment: @jotik agree. I don't believe the information is available except in the reflog, since remotely it's just another commit, right?

Comment: Correct. I don't know whether the remote (usually bare) repository has a reflog, but if it does, it's most likely not identical to the local reflog.

Comment: Thanks for responses.
Reflog is what I am lokking for partially, but I need that information from the remote side, since I need that information in a Hook pre-recieved of the remote so I can so some actions with pushed cherry-picked commits. Is there no any way from the remote?
Thanks.