# Getting full commit history after git clone

Tags: git, clone, reflog

I'm the lone developer on a project where I'm working across multiple computers, some on VM. After doing a git clone of my repo on gitHub, calls to reflog only show items *after* the clone. How can I update this new cloned repo to show the full history?

Comment: Is there some specific functionality that you're looking for beyond what, for example, `git log` provides?

Comment: Looking into it, I think part of this issue was my ignorance of the difference between reflow and log. Log seems to give me more what I'm looking for, thanks for bringing that up!

Comment: semi-related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098095/git-can-i-view-the-reflog-of-a-remote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reflog only shows the history of things you have done to your repository. It is kind of like a local history. This means the first thing you did was clone the repository, and so that is where it starts. I do not believe what you are asking is technically possible.

There are lots of ways to accomplish tasks in Git though. Perhaps you can accomplish your root goal using something other than reflog.

Comment: I was trying to do a `git rebase -i` but did not see the full history of the branch. Can i issue the same command to the remote/ will this do what I'm expecting?

Comment: Make sure you have performed a `git fetch` for the branch you are trying to rebase against. You may also need to check out a local copy of that branch.

Comment: I've done this, but still get no commit history to pick from. Can I do `git rebase -i origin/branch` and get what I'm expecting?

Comment: `git checkout -b myBranch origin/branch` then do `git rebase -i myBranch`