# How can I see the previous position of a remote branch (a-la reflog)?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

The tip of a remote branch was moved to a commit with a completely different story than the previous one, creating all sorts of issues when pulling changes from the branch. Is it there a way to find out what caused this? Nobody on the team recollects having anything to do with it. And we sure don't want to have this problem again.
We are using Atlassian Stash.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098095/git-can-i-view-the-reflog-of-a-remote#10098641