# Recover git commit that was never local

Tags: git

I was working on local/feature, created remote/feature and pushed my work there.

A coworker pushed to remote/feature.

I noticed a mistake in local/feature, didn't want to create unnecessary commits on my feature branch, so I amended the commit to correct the mistake, and used git push --force to overwrite remote/feature.

I have the hash of my coworkers commit, is there any way I can restore it?
Git doesn't recognize the hash locally.

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be for your coworker to re-push their changes that they should still have on their machine. In the future don't force push unless you know you're safe to do so..

Comment: Do you have access to the remote repo?

Comment: @chevybow The coworker wasn't available at the time. And yes, I should have checked before force pushing.

Comment: @melpomene I do have access to the remote repo.

Comment: I also have access to the body of the overwritten commit through bitbucket, and could recreate the commit if that is the best fix.

Comment: Then `git checkout -b choose_a_name THECOMMITHASH` should work. You'll have a new branch you can then merge or revert or whatever.

Comment: @melpomene git fails with "reference is not a tree: THECOMMITHASH" when I run that.

Comment: If you're using GitHub, maybe this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35273807/5182932

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the comments.

As to the problem at hand, if you are in a hurry, recreate the commit and add `--author="That Guy"` to `git commit` to honour the author.

Also warn you colleague ASAP, so they know what is happening and don't spend time fixing problems that don't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try this option [recover from githubs-reflog](https://objectpartners.com/2014/02/11/recovering-a-commit-from-githubs-reflog/) suggested by @sp0gg in comment

Never user `--force` use  `--force-with-lease`  instead. 
it ensures that you don't overwrite other's work.

ref: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/