# Does git fetch pick up deleted branches?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch

Use case:

User A's working on branch A forked from master; user B creates branch B forked from master does some work and commits and then deletes branch B. Can user A ever see the work of user B (e.g. `git fetch --all`). User A has never worked on branch B.

In this case branch B is not showing up for user A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

The long answer is [Mu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)): the question as asked is actually meaningless, unless one makes some leaps of interpretation (which I think most people will).  The reason is that *branches don't matter; you don't (quite) fetch branches*.  What matters are *commits*, so the correct question is whether `git fetch` will fetch these *commits* (and *then* the answer is generally "no" ).

I think you have a mistaken idea here too:

> e.g. `git fetch --all`

The `--all` option to `git fetch` means *all remotes*, not *all branches*.

The rest of this answer is optional, but I suggest it is worth reading: you'll find out when the answer becomes "yes".

#### How Git works

We begin with the following:

- A Git repository is, at its heart, a pair of databases:

  - One database holds *commits* and other Git internal objects.  These store every version of every file for all time, more or less.
  - But commits (and other objects) are numbered with huge, useless-to-humans, seemingly-random numbers ("hash IDs" or "object IDs").  To make these things accessible to humans and thus useful, the *other* databse in a Git repository translates from *names* to the internal numbers.
- The names in a Git repository include branch names, but these are not the only kind of name.  There are also tag names, funny things called *remote-tracking names* or *remote-tracking branch names*, and so on.  People (rather mistakenly) sometimes call the remote-tracking names "remote branch names", but this is quite misleading.
- The act of *cloning* a Git repository means *get me all the commits and none of the branches*.  (This is somewhat modifiable via various options, and does not capture all the details, but it's the right starting point for viewing cloning.)  Git does not need branches.  It needs only *commits* and some *names by which to find them*.

When we work locally, in a Git repository we've cloned or built from scratch or whatever, we do in fact get our work done using branch names.  But these branch names are *created in **our** repository*.  They are not in any other repository!  Because humans are humans, though, we tend to use the *same* names in two different clones:

- Bob has a repository.  In Bob's repository, Bob created branches named `alpha` and `beta`.
- I clone Bob's repository.  I don't get his branch names: I create *my own* branch names.  But because I intend to work *with* Bob, I call *my* branches `alpha` and `beta` too.

These are the "same names", and initially they may hold the same commit ID numbers as well.  But my names are *mine* and Bob's names are *Bob's*.  They only meet up if and when we synchronize them.

When I first clone Bob's repository, I get, from him, all of his commits and none of his branches: I have no branches at all.  But my Git *does* remember his *branch names*.  My Git sticks those names *into* my repository under the general category of *remote-tracking names*.  That is, instead of `alpha`, I get `bob/alpha`.  Instead of `beta`, I get `bob/beta`.  These are *my Git's memory of Bob's branch names*.

Now, since I intend to work on/with the same commit that Bob published recently, I choose one of these two names and have my Git *create*, for me, a branch *of the same name:* I now have either an `alpha` or a `beta` (but not both).  Since any name holds one internal Git object ID, my `alpha` or `beta`—whichever it is I choose to create—holds the *same* commit hash ID as my `bob/alpha` or `bob/beta`.  That's the hash ID I got *from* Bob when I got all the commits from Bob, and turned Bob's *branch* names into my *remote-tracking* names.

#### How `git fetch` works

Over time, Bob may or may not have made new commits.  At some point, I decide I should have my Git, working with *my* clone, which has *my* branches (plus of course all the commits, plus my remote-tracking names), call up Bob's Git again, and have Bob's Git connect to Bob's repository.

At this point, Bob has whatever branches he has.  His Git (his software, running on his repository) lists out these branch names to my Git (my software, running on my repository).  These come with commit hash IDs: those big ugly random-looking numbers for the commit objects.

My Git checks to see whether I have those commits.  If I do, great!  If not, my Git asks Bob's Git for those commits, which causes a whole conversation to run so that my Git can find out *all* the *new* commits Bob has that I don't.  My Git downloads *all* these commits, and now I have all the commits Bob has, again, just like when I first cloned.  Finally, now that I have all of Bob's commits—plus maybe my own, on my branches—my Git updates my *remote-tracking* names to remember Bob's branch names and commits.

**Note that this has no effect on any of my branches.**  I do, however, get updates to my remote-tracking names—and if Bob created a *new* branch name, and my Git saw it during this `git fetch`, my Git will create a *new* remote-tracking name to go with that.  If I set `fetch.prune` or use `-p`, and Bob *deleted* some of his branch names, my Git will *delete* the corresponding remote-tracking names, too.  So `git fetch` updates, for me, the remote-tracking names for the Git I called up.

The key questions here are: *What Git did I call up, and what names and commits did that Git have?*  I say here that I called up Bob's Git, which had Bob's branch names and all the commits Bob has, so we can answer these questions and see what remote-tracking names I have now, and what object hash IDs those names hold.

#### Introducing "forks" and/or "central repositories"

In the above, I've been using Bob's computer directly.  When I run `git fetch`, I get ssh access (or whatever) *to* Bob's computer, logging in to it in some way so that I can run Git commands over there.  That's fine in some Linux-server-type environments, like a corporate Git setup.  But many places don't want to work like this, and/or want to have a single "source of truth" centralized repository, whether that's hosted in-company or on GitHub or whatever.

So now I won't *have* access to Bob's repository, on Bob's computer.  Instead, there's a centralized repo somewhere that—at least initially—has only *one branch*, named `master`.  Bob will clone that centralized repo and get `origin/master` and use that to create, in Bob's Git, `master`.  Bob then uses his `master` to create a new branch name `alpha`.

When I connect to the central repository, my Git makes *my* clone, which has all the commits and no branch names and one remote-tracking name `origin/master`.  I (or my Git anyway) use my `origin/master` to create a branch named `master`, which I then use to create my branch name `beta`.

When I run `git fetch`, my Git goes over to `origin`.  Bob hasn't told the Git over on `origin` to create *any* new branch names.  So I won't see *any* of *Bob's* branch names at all, because I never talk directly to Bob's Git, and I won't see any of Bob's branch names copied over to `origin` because he has not done that yet.

When Bob eventually runs a `git push`, he does:

```
git push -u origin alpha
```

This makes his Git call up the Git over at `origin` and offer to it—to the `origin` Git—any commits Bob has on `alpha` that `origin` does not already have.<sup>1</sup>  They take those commits, and then Bob asks the origin Git to create, on origin, a *new branch name*, `alpha`.  If the origin Git obeys this request—that's up to the origin Git and any control knobs someone may have installed and adjusted (basic Git doesn't have much here, but most hosting sites do)—then *now* the origin Git has a branch named `alpha`.

My Git, calling up the Git at `origin`, can now see `alpha`, and create my `origin/alpha` remote-tracking name (after getting those five, or whatever, new-to-my-Git commits).  That's a *remote-tracking name* for me, and a branch name for `origin`, but I can only see it *because* Bob convinced `origin` to create it.

If Bob decides to make a GitHub-style *fork*, what he's done is make yet another clone, but this time one hosted on GitHub.  Bob's clone is *another separate Git repository* and this clone has its own branch names.  There's a  special thing or two about this clone though: when GitHub creates it, GitHub *does* copy all the branches, so initially that clone has all the same branches as the `origin` clone I'll be using.  Also, as Bob creates new commits and branch names *on* Bob's GitHub fork, Bob can make *pull request* to the `origin` Git.  (That's all stuff GitHub offers as add-ons, to make you want to use GitHub rather than doing self-hosting.)

In all these cases, until Bob somehow causes a new branch to come into existence on the `origin` Git, I can't see Bob's *commits*.  I can only see the *branch names* that are on `origin`, which will become my remote-tracking names; and I can only get Bob's commits once he's given them *to* the `origin` Git somehow, and made a name *on* the `origin` Git so that I—or my Git—can find their commit hash ID numbers.

---

<sup>1</sup>This phrasing covers the fact that all the commits that were on `master` are now on *both branches*.  So the Git at `origin` has a ton of commits that are on `alpha`; it's just that Bob has five *more* commits, or however many Bob made.

---

#### Remotes

In the above process, my Git has always had exactly one *remote*.

When I was using the example where I went directly into Bob's computer—which let me see all of Bob's branches any time I did that—I used the name `bob` for this remote, so that my *remote-tracking names* were `bob/alpha` and `bob/beta`.

When I was using GitHub as an example, I used the name `origin` for the remote, so that my remote-tracking names were `origin/master` and, eventually (once Bob created an `alpha` there too) `origin/alpha`.

A *remote* is primarily a short name for a URL.  The URL I might use for Bob's computer might be `ssh://bob.company.com/path/to/repo.git`.  The URL I might use for GitHub might be `ssh://git@github.com/company/repo.git`.

The `git clone` command will, by default, make your new clone have, as its (one, single) remote, the remote name `origin`.  This name will store the URL you gave *to* `git clone`, so that later, `git fetch origin` will go back to the same URL and get any new commits from them.

You can, however, have more than one remote.  The only constraint here is that each one has to have a unique name.  So if I *do* have direct access to Bob's computer, I can *add* that to my clone in which `origin` refers to the GitHub clone ... and *now* I *can* access Bob's repository directly, and hence see Bob's branches, as my `bob/*` remote-tracking names.  So now the answer **changes** from *no, I can't see Bob's branches* to *yes, I can see Bob's branches*.  I will have `origin/master`, but also `bob/alpha` (and `bob/master` too, unless he deleted his name `master`).

Now that I have more than one *remote*, running `git fetch --all` has a meaning.  Before, with just the one remote named `origin`, `git fetch --all` means *fetch from all remotes*, which means *fetch from `origin`*, which is what `git fetch` without `--all` means: there's just the one remote, so *the* remote is the one we fetch from.

With *two* remotes, though, `git fetch` with no additional qualifier means *fetch from **some** remote*.  Which one?  [The `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) here is not a model of clarity, but the answer currently is:

- if I am on branch *B* and *B* has a configured *remote* of *R*, that's the one `git fetch` uses;
- otherwise, `git fetch` falls back on the name `origin`.

(This might change someday.)

If I give `git fetch` a name like `origin` or `bob`, that's the one remote it will fetch from, and there are more options such as "remote groups" and of course `--all`.  Using `--all` directs `git fetch` to run `git fetch` on *all* remotes, one at a time.<sup>2</sup>

So: `--all` is only *useful* if you've defined two or more remotes.  If you *have* set up remote access to Bob's repository, you *can* see Bob's branches.  This of course requires that you have *access* to Bob's machine, or Bob's fork on GitHub, or whatever.

---

<sup>2</sup>Ideally Git should run multiple parallel fetches, but currently it doesn't.

---

#### Conclusion

In the end, the real key here is *commits*.  We get *commits* by their hash IDs.  We *find* those hash IDs through names—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, whatever names.  The `git fetch` command reaches out to some other Git (software+repository).  By default, it uses *their* branch names (and their tag names, depending on `--tags` and other fetch options) to find commits to get, gets those commits, and then creates or updates names in *our* repository, but with the standard setup, the names we get in our repository for their *branch* names are our *remote-tracking* names instead.

The only names we can *see* are those that they offer us, and they can only offer us the names that they have.  So if "their Git" is a centralized repository somewhere, and Bob creates branches in Bob's clone and makes commits there but never sends the names *or* commits to the centralized repository, the centralized repository never has anything to give us in the first place.

Comment: Neatly explained! But if Bob pushes to the centralized repository and later deletes the branch names, there will be "dangling" commits on the remote; `git fetch` can't fetch them right? In this case I start working on the repo after Bob has already created, pushed and deleted a branch to/from the remote

Comment: Yes: if Bob creates branch `temp` on the central repo and puts some temporary commits there, then asks the central repo to delete `temp`, the commits themselves may linger, but without a reference, `git fetch` won't *see* them and therefore won't retrieve them. This is not *guaranteed:* in particular, some site might optimize `git clone` by just sending every commit even if there's no ref for it, allowing an Evil Attacker to see nominally-deleted commits. But you won't see them in normal practice ... *unless* you fetch from the central repo during the period when `temp` exists.

Comment: Since there is no way to close the race between Alice (fetching from central repo while `temp` exists) and Bob (creating, then later deleting, `temp`), we should in general assume that any commit pushed *to* the central repo has been grabbed by everyone who has access to the central repo. But Alice, in our hypothetical setup here, won't have to worry about those commits as long as she doesn't *look* for `temp`, and if she has `fetch.prune` set to `true` she'll drop `origin/temp` locally as soon as she fetches from central when `temp` doesn't exist.

Comment: alright; thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that users A and B are on different computers (A and B) and that the master branch is stored on a server.

#### First

Make a list of repository that have known branch B.

- The one used by user B on computer B.
- The one on the server. If user B had pushed branch B on the server.
- Others ? (user B had pushed branch B on a backup repository).

#### Second

Make sure that the branch have been deleted from all those repository. If not, A can retrieve branch B from here (ex : the server).

#### Finally

Take a look at [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), it provides the recent history of `HEAD`(local) and can help user B to retrieve branch B after delete. Some git servers also have some identical feature (like github as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098095/git-can-i-view-the-reflog-of-a-remote)).