# How to get GitHub REST API to restore a deleted branch

Tags: github-api

I've been looking for a way to automate a task, one manual part that needs automation is this restore branch button, is there a way to do this using Github API? I've read these two documents and couldn't find anything, Thank you.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/branches

[image: same functionality as this button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following off the advice from here: [git can I view the reflog of a remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098095/git-can-i-view-the-reflog-of-a-remote)

I was able to restore a PR branch via the GitHub CLI/API by...

Getting the SHA of the HEAD of the branch to restore with:

`gh pr view {pr_number} --json commits`

where the last commit in the "commits" array will have a "oid" value (which I believe stands for orphan id), and that can be used to create the restored branch with

```
gh api repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/refs -f ref=refs/heads/{new_branch_name} -f sha={oid}

# set new_branch_name to the name of the PR branch to keep same behavior as button
```

and now the branch can be fetch'd when within a cloned instance of the repository:

`git fetch`

but is also available via API as there is now a new remote branch

*Sorry if you can't use gh. This worked for me and I don't mind the dependency. If someone likes they can figure out a full REST API only way.*