# How to find out which files have been changed between two pushes in a GitLab merge request?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Imagine this scenario:

- I create a merge request where I modified a file in `src/`. This triggers a long-running test job in the CI/CD pipeline.
- I forgot to update the readme, so I push another commit. **I don't want to run the long-running test again, since the readme is not in `src/`.**

My idea now is to check the files that have changed between pipeline 1 and 2. We've enabled [merged results pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html) (so GitLab creates a commit with the result of the source and target branches merged together when running pipelines).

My merge request has these pipelines:

| Pipeline ID | Pipeline Type | Commit SHA | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #1 | merged results | fca36db3 | First push with changes to `src/` |
| #2 | merged results | 6cb35df4 | Second push with changes to the readme |

My CI/CD job looks like this:

```yaml
job:
  script:
    - git diff fca36db3..6cb35df4 --
```

The output:

```txt
$ git diff fca36db3..6cb35df4 --
fatal: bad revision 'fca36db3..6cb35df4'
```

Obviously the merge commits created by GitLab aren't available here. I've tried to set `GIT_STRATEGY` to `clone` and `GIT_DEPTH` to `0`, without success. Is it even possible to work with these commits?

Comment: Do a fetch specifying the _other_ commit so that git can have all information it needs to do the diff.

Comment: Something like `git fetch origin --depth=1 fca36db3` (or the other commit, i don't know which one you are working on).

Comment: This command would just clone the entire repo into a folder called `fca36db3`, right? I found a solution which I posted as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Nope... I assume you are already sitting (a person, the pipeline, whoever) on the repo and that you are on a shallow clone of one one of the commits involved in the diff, right? So, you need to get the information about the _other_ commit locally.... and how do you do that? With a `fetch`  (not `clone`) specifying the commit you want to get. use `--depth=1` so you do not pull the full history of the other commit.

Comment: Right, somehow misread that. `fetch` didn't work for me first, but I realised I must use the full sha instead of the short one to get it working. Thanks! Would you like to create an answer for that?

Comment: I don't think using the full commit id is necessary _but_ I might be wrong on that. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get these commits from another repository by creating a branch off of them. Idea from [Can I view the reflog of a remote (not remote ref)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098095/can-i-view-the-reflog-of-a-remote-not-remote-ref/35273807#35273807)

```yaml
job:
  script:
    - curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/branches?branch=branch-for-fca36db3&ref=fca36db3"
    - git fetch origin branch-for-fca36db3
    - curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/branches?branch=branch-for-6cb35df4&ref=6cb35df4"
    - git fetch origin branch-for-6cb35df4
    - git diff fca36db3..6cb35df4 --
```

Comment: There is no need tor you to create a ref to be able to pick up that commit... as long as the commit is in the history of one public ref, git will be happy to serve it, so you can do `git fetch <some-remote> <some-commit-id>`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a filtering approach by dispatching pipelines from a job depending on what files have changed between commits. We're using this on a monorepo structure with each folder having its own `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and it's working quite well.

A dispatching/filtering job would look like this:

```
variables:
  DEFAULT_COMMIT: "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" # This is GitLab's default value for a newly created branch

.dispatcher:
  stage: Dispatch
  trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include: $PROJECT_DIR/.gitlab-ci.yml
    forward:
      yaml_variables: true
      pipeline_variables: true
  rules:
      # Checks for first commit on branch - we compare changes to the values we have in main
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == $DEFAULT_COMMIT
      changes:
        paths:
          - $PROJECT_DIR/**/* # This is the filter
        compare_to: main # On first push you just compare with `main`
      variables:
        SOURCE: "commit"
        FOLDER: $PROJECT_DIR
      # If commit is not the first one - we compare changes with the previous commit
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA != $DEFAULT_COMMIT
      changes:
        paths:
          - $PROJECT_DIR/**/*
      variables:
        SOURCE: "commit"
        FOLDER: $PROJECT_DIR
      # If it's a commit and we're on main branch, indicates we're merging changes
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      changes:
        paths:
          - $PROJECT_DIR/**/*
      variables:
        SOURCE: "merge"
        FOLDER: $PROJECT_DIR
```

The `variables` defined on each of those jobs are totally optional but we use them on the downstream pipelines to have context of the event that triggered the pipeline and execute a different action depending if it's a merge/commit.

Comment: Interesting! The usage of `$CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA` implies your running this on `push` pipelines, right? We're only running `merge_request_event` (more specific: merged results) pipelines for our merge requests, as the test jobs should consider the latest changes from the target branch. Furthermore, we've disabled `push` pipelines, as they are capable of making our MRs mergable ("Pipelines must succeed" setting in Settings -> Merge requests -> Merge checks).

Comment: Yes that's right we have a completely opposite setup, we just use push pipelines to handle everything and execute different jobs depending whether we've just commit or merged changes to a branch. I was taking a look at the docs and maybe you can achieve the same using `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_DIFF_BASE_SHA` or `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA`?