# Show all stashes in git log

Tags: git, git-log, git-stash

I would like to see all stashes in `git log` output. Does anyone know if there is a way to do that?

Edit: I want to see all commits in the log -- *including* stash commits. I tried the command:

```
git log --date-order --all
```

But it returns only the top most stash. I would like to see commits that represent other stashes too.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I came here looking to do the same as @jbialobr, I did some more digging after reading the previous answers and came up with the below.

@msmt's answer gives you a log of the stashes, and you can use this to get the hashes to use in the git log.

`git reflog show --format="%h" stash` gives you just the hashes of all stashes which can then be passed to a git log command such as

`git log --date-order --all $(git reflog show --format="%h" stash)`

The full command I personally am now using is

`git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all $(git reflog show --format="%h" stash)`

Tested on git version 2.5.1 on centos

Comment: SicoAnimal, you're an awesome human. Your only contribution to SO, with [until now; for over a year] 0 votes, is definitely one for the config file. Thank you!

Comment: I would use xargs with this as it's more readable and easier to work with: ```git reflog show --format="%h" stash | xargs git show```

Comment: This does show the stashes as part of the output, but there are no labels except for the first one, so it's hard to find them in the log.

Answer (score 62):

You can show all your stashes with `git stash list`. Maybe you can write a script to show both `git stash list` and `git log` and use it with an alias.

Answer (score 22):

Not sure what you mean. stash is a branch and you can list all stashes with `git log -g stash`.

Comment: Better, it shows all stashes, but now it doesn't show index and untracked files commits that are related to stashes. Command git log -z --all --boundary shows them, but when I add -g stash, then these commits are no longer in log output.

Comment: Just spelling this out a bit more: `stash` is short for `refs/stash` the list of all of the stash heads, and `-g` (or `--walk-refs`) tells `log` to step through the items in the reference list, rather than following the modification history back from each stash commit.

Answer (score 7):

Another easy way to do this is `git reflog show stash`

Comment: Have you read my Edit note? I know how to list stashes. I would like to include the all stashes in the output of the `git log` command.

Comment: @jbialobr I guess your question was a bit ambiguous to me. It looked like you knew how to log all the commits but you were looking for how to see just stashes. The ambiguity for me is at, `I would like to see commits that represent other stashes.` If `git log --all` is not working for you then I would have to second what @robinr said, "Not sure what you mean".

Answer (score 4):

For git version 2.2.3 or later, you can simply use the [`--reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/#Documentation/git-log.txt---reflog) option of `git log`.

```
git log --graph --oneline --all --reflog
```

In addition, [it also shows dangling commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548567/9157799).

Answer (score 3):

**To get the tree graph with everything: all branches, all stashes at your fingertips...**

---

*Expanding on a [super-useful answer from SicoAnimal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35993495/5109693), so you don't have to type out all this stuff (especially useful with remote SSH sessions where you don't have any kind of Git UI)*...

---

**1. Setup git aliases:**

```bash
# Short and sweet: hashes and graph with all branches and stashes
git config --global alias.l \
    '!sh -c '"'"' git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate $(git stash list --format="%h") '"'"' '

# Same as above + dates and emails
git config --global alias.ll \
    '!sh -c '"'"' git log --graph --all --date=format:"'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"'" --pretty=format:"'"%C(yellow)%h%Creset%C(auto)%d%Creset %C(cyan)%cd%Creset %s %C(green)(%ce)%Creset"'" $(git stash list --format="%h") '"'"' '
```

**2. Use aliases**:

```bash
# Short and sweet: hashes and graph with all branches and stashes
git l

# Same as above + dates and emails
git ll
```

**3. Sweet result**:

Notice that you can see all stashes, not only the latest one on a the given commit (shown with arrows).

[image]

---

References:

[How to create a Git alias with nested commands with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881240/5109693)

Comment: If you use `git stash list --format=%H` (as suggested in a comment above by @tangle) you won't have the problem when there are no stashes

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip! Updated my answer: now it uses `git stash list`.

Answer (score 2):

Full command:

`git log --oneline --graph --all $(git stash list --format="%H")`

Where list of heads of stashes:

`git stash list --format="%H"`

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford having a graphical GUI, take a look at `gitk`.

It shows you branches, tags, remote branches stashes etc. In a visually not appealing, but very compact and useful form. It usually comes along with "git" package in your package manager and works if you also have "tk" (the GUI toolkit it uses).

Comment: It shows only the topmost stash by default. If you have a way to make it show more than that, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @NeilMayhew, try setting _View Menu_ -> _Edit View..._ -> _Command to generate more commits to include_ to `git stash list --format=%H`.

Comment: @tangle Fantastic! Thank you. Works perfectly.