"git log --all" - show multiple stashes
While using git, I noticed that my git GUI client (Git Extensions) shows all stashes I have if "show unrelated histories" is enabled - see below screenshot.

However, when looking at "git log" (git log --oneline --all --graph), only stash@{0} is visible, listed as refs/stash (see below)

Can I configure git-log to show all stashes, not just the stash at the top of the stack?

@terrorrussia-keeps-killing no - that question is about excluding stashes, not showing multiple. Almost the opposite of what I'm looking for, really.

Ah sorry! My bad. Apologies.

I'm not sure if I understand how git stashes really work, but as far as I remember they all reside in the only refs/stash ref (I mean there is no anything like refs/stash/1, etc). Not sure, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988929/show-all-stashes-in-git-log seems to be the only way of doing that in git-log. At least git log --all $(git reflog show --format="%h" stash) seems to do that, but the refs/stash points to the latest stash only, other stash refs are not decorated at all. It's really clunky.

Using git-reflog to generate a list of stash hashes seems to be kind of, let's say, fragile (sorry can't pick a better word) to me, however stashes are able to survive git-gc. Perhaps you can also iterate over stash@{0}, stash@{1} and so on (if the index is overflowing the current number of stash entries, unless something like fatal: log for 'stash' only has 2 entries is reported).

The git-stash doc says that refs/stash points to the latest stash only, stash refs are stored in the reflog, not all of them reside in the single ref and I said before. git-gc can destroy stash entrries from the reflog completely, say by specifying -c gc.refs/stash.reflogExpireUnreachable=$(date +%s), and git stash list shows nothing after the reflog is purged. The closest workaround I can think of is assigning a dedicated ref to each stash to make them appear decorated in git log, but I really doubt it's worth of doing that.
