# How to find commit in all branches based on part of id

Tags: git

How can I find commit in all branches? In my case it is more than 20 branches and I've only part of commit id. I know only that it is part of begin or end commits id. All branches excludes one are remote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a combination [`--contains`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---containsltcommitgt) option with finding a commit from the revision list using [`rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)

```
git branch -a --contains $(git rev-list --all | grep <your-partial-commit-id>)
```

It finds first the full commit id using the partial with

```
git rev-list --all | grep <your-partial-commit-id>
```

And then you pass the full commit id to search in all the branches using the -a option (for all branches), with the commit id passed to the `--contains` argument

```
git branch -a --contains <your-full-commit-id>
```

**Additional Note**: In your case, this is not true, but if it is known that the partial id is the beginning part of the full commit id (any length), then you can just directly pass it to `git branch --contains` without getting the full id from the `rev-list` command

Comment: Yes for `branch --contains`. I was in the process of writing a similar answer. This is the way to go.

Comment: It's correct answer but this command works only in bash shell.

Comment: @Rav3 True. For any other means, you'd need to use the way for that particular medium to be able to pass the output of one command to the other

Comment: @Vandesh in my case I used WSL.

Answer (score 0):

this command will save your life

```
git reflog
```

reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786972/get-a-list-of-all-git-commits-including-the-lost-ones)

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work. I am running this command in one of my branch directory and I've got only one commit.

Comment: see my image works for me maybe something else going on in your branch

Answer (score 0):

```
git rev-list --all | grep <your-partial-sha1>
```

... will output all of the commits from your repository whose SHA-1 matches.