# Show git commits without branch reference in graph

Tags: git

After we change the git history (ie. by `git rebase`), we will have some commits without branch reference, until the garbage collector eventually will delete them.

I would like to visualize every commit, including these without branch reference in a graph. So in case I would need to go back to an unreferenced commit after a rebase, I could have the whole picture, and avoid use `git reflog`.

[image]

Comment: this other response replies my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/23780964/2786832, as the graph part was important for me